# So i try to add gatsby-plugin-favicon in my gatsby-config.js file

Tags: webpack, gatsby

First i add gatsby-plugin-favicon in my gatsby-config.js file 
the code following :

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Chatbiz Blog',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-catch-links',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-favicon',
      options: {
        logo: "./src/images/icon.png",
        icons: {
          android: true,
          appleIcon: true,
          appleStartup: true,
          coast: false,
          favicons: true,
          firefox: true,
          twitter: false,
          yandex: false,
          windows: false
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

After finish add gatsby-plugin-favicon, i got a error like this

```
WebpackError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\setia\myrep  ository\GatsbyJS\gatsby_crash_course\public\.iconstats.json'
```

so the question how do i solve the problem?

Comment: did you run and install the plugin and any dependencies?  `npm i gatsby-plugin-favicon` or yarn add `gatsby-plugin-favicon` ?

Comment: @NickC already install the plugin, but still can't work 
i still get the error

Comment: try `yarn cache clean` could be package management bug

Answer (score 0):

Go to **gatsby-config.js** file and remove the dependency mention below

```
icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`,
```